# how to get exact content from CK Editor and display in custom window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, ckeditor

I have used CK Editor to create contents to display in a new window, mostly it is working fine but just the bullet list and number list are not displaying as I created.

- the first image will be the content I created  in CK Editor
  [image]
- the second image will be the preview after I click the preview button in CK Editor tools.
  [image]
- the last image will be the display in my custom window.
  [image]

In this case, I am confused where to look and what to change in order to fix this bugs. Why is it different from the preview and what can I do to make it look the same?

Comment: Did you inspect the CSS applied to the list entries? Maybe the CSS classes used to style the bullets are not available in the custom window.

Comment: Your custom window probably applies some styles that override the default list style that you can see in CKeditor. Be careful when applying global styles, or else display the CKeditor content directly inside a frame to avoid style collisions